# Is paired t test same with two sample t test for correlated data?

Tags: time-series, t-test

I was asked to perform a two-sample t-test for correlated data. When I search for that, I barely found a source mentioning this name. Almost all the sources used paired sample t-test but I want to be sure if paired sample t-test and two sample t-test for correlated data are the same test.

I have 4 samples (4 huts with different roofs) with 4000 data points for each. (temperature (°C)). It is time series data.

Comment: What do you mean by "correlated data"? Correlated in what way? Can you give us some context, what these represent?

Comment: I have four different samples(one control, and three experimental groups) based on temperature data over 1 year, and they are correlated. (data gathered from inside temperature of 4 different huts) I want to test if there is a statistical difference between these groups

Comment: When you say you have four different samples, do you mean you have a total of 4 data points in all the groups? Or that you have 4 groups, each having multiple data points? Since you mention that you have data over 1 year, is this time series data? Do you have measurements from one and the same process within groups?

Comment: I have 4 groups (4 huts with different roofs) with 4000  data points for each.(temperature (°C)). It is time series data.  The answer of the last question is yes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should include this information into your question with more context as appropriate. Because you admitted this is time series data then most standard tests (such as a t-test and its non-parametric variants) are not appropriate anymore (because of the unit independence assumption, that is your samples are autocorrelated).

Comment: It seems you have multiple time series observations and one way to test if the group means are equal is to run a linear mixed model. If the sample is regularly measured, try using ARMA errors. As highlighted by @user2974951, you cannot apply paired t-test here since you have dependence between sample units, i.e. time points.